# Enums in lambda expressions are compiled differently; consequence of overload resolution improvements?

Tags: c#, lambda, enums, roslyn, c#-6.0

While trying out the Visual Studio 2015 RC, I received a run-time error on previously working code.  Given the lambda  `(x => x.CustomerStatusID == CustomerStatuses.Active)` which was passed to a function as an `Expression<>`, the debugger shows a difference in the expression tree.  Formerly it compiled as this:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Services.DataClasses.CustomerDC,System.Boolean]>(Services.DataClasses.CustomerDC $x)
{
    (System.Int32)$x.CustomerStatusID == 0
}
```

But in C# 6.0 it now compiles as

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Services.DataClasses.CustomerDC,System.Boolean]>(Services.DataClasses.CustomerDC $x)
{
    (System.Int32)$x.CustomerStatusID == (System.Int32).Constant<Services.DataClasses.CustomerStatuses>(Active)
}
```

Although the fix to my tree-traversing code was straightforward and the additional detail is appreciated, does anyone know of any other gotchas floating around like this?

Alternately, does anyone have a link to information on the specifics of how overload resolution was improved?  I cannot find any.

Comment: What was the runtime exception type and message?

Comment: @ErikPhilips There is no exception. Simply put, before (<= 4.5) the compiler would have built an expression of type `Expression.Constant(0)` (so `int`), while with Roslyn it more correctly builds an expression of type `Expression.Constant(CustomerStatuses.Active)`, so using an enum with its value. Technically it builds an expression like `Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(CustomerStatuses.Active), typeof(int))`. Considering that `0` is specially handled as an enum value, I've tested it with `1`. Same result.

Comment: You should update your question, your first sentence states `I received a run-time error on previously working code`.

Comment: Result of online tryroslyn, where it can be seen: http://goo.gl/a2vmaS

Comment: This is only an issue with 0 value of the enum, correct? I suspect it has to do with the compiler doing some sort of optimization with the default value, that it really shouldn't have done for expression trees and was considered a bug.

Comment: @xanatos "I've tested it with 1. Same result." You mean there is no difference between compilers or the same difference exists?

Comment: @mikez No... That the handling of `0` and the handling of `1` is the same, so different between C# 5.0 and 6.0 (at least on tryroslyn)

Comment: @xanatos Yes I see it now. You can actually just run ToString on both and see that the output is different ([.NET 4.5](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HjSHJd) vs [Roslyn](https://dotnetfiddle.net/an9kHz)). I still think it probably changed because it was considered a bug, but I don't see anything in the roslyn repo or connect at first glance.

Comment: xanatos is correct. Without our defensive coding practices we might have eventually gotten an ordinary NullRef, or worse, silently wrong results. My worry is I can't find any literature on this C# 6.0 change because the new syntatic sugar and feature-adds steal the spotlight. All I've ever seen on the overloading change is a vague mention of nullables, but without examples. Hence I ask the community.

Comment: @RonNewcomb It is surely a breaking change... And it adds a third way that a comparison with an enum could be written: `(int)property == num`, `(int)property == (int)enumValue`, `property == enumValue` (the third one is the one you would normally write if you write an Expression tree "manually")

Comment: You should post/ask this on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/ if you haven't already.

Comment: IIRC, the precise way expressions are transformed into expression trees is intentionally underspecified. The result of that is that you can easily get differences between different compilers. I don't have any documentation or other reference about it though. Anyway, this is unrelated to overload resolution.

Comment: This article has many explanations about c# 6 http://blog.slaks.net/2014-05-28/exploring-roslyn-part-3-breaking-changes/#overload-resolution-with-conflicting-ambiguities

Comment: Not sure is th same issue, since you are not posting the detail of the error but, in my case was data type miss match in my db I have the enum type as small int and these were giving issue when converting to a enum I change those to int in the database and works, again not sure if same issue since you don't put error information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with overload resolution. The previous compiler prematurely optimized the right-hand-side of the comparison, thereby omitting the code corresponding to the source expression.