# Does Roslyn change the way of compiling an expression that uses Nullable enum?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, .net-4.6

The following code prints different results between VS2015 and VS2013:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    enum YesNo
    {
        Yes,
        No
    }

    class MyType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public YesNo? YesNo { get; set; }        
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Expression<Func<MyType, bool>> expr = (MyType x) => x.YesNo == YesNo.Yes;
            Console.WriteLine(expr.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

The result from VS2013 (without VS2015 installed) is:

```
x => (Convert(x.YesNo) == Convert(Yes))
```

However the result from VS2015 is:

```
x => (Convert(x.YesNo) == Convert(Convert(Yes)))
```

This difference is currently causing an issue for us. Also a Telerik customer [found the same issue](http://www.telerik.com/forums/net-4-6-enum-in-where-expression)

We are using BLToolkit for data access, the current issue we have is that:

Originally (purely on VS2013), the

```
People.Where(i=>i.YesNo == Yes.Yes)
```

will be converted into

```
x => (Convert(x.YesNo) == Convert(Yes))
```

and then is converted into

```
x => x.YesNo == Y
```

and then eventually is translated into SQL

```
select * from Person p
where p.YesNo = 'Y'
```

which is a correct result.

However, now, the same query (expression) is translated into

```
x => (Convert(x.YesNo) == Convert(Convert(Yes)))
```

which is converted into

```
x => x.YesNo == Convert(Y)
then
x => x.YesNo == 1
```

then this is translated into SQL

```
select * from Person p
where p.YesNo = '1'
```

which is unexpected to us.

Is this difference caused by design or is this a bug?

Is this issue caused by .NET Roslyn compiler or .NET 4.6 ?

Comment: I think that question is better to be asked on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: Yes, I recall something being changed about a certain enum value in Roslyn. Would you say this is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538335/enums-in-lambda-expressions-are-compiled-differently-consequence-of-overload-re)?

Comment: I recall reading that Roslyn changed expressions for enums.  It's not a bug, the expression is still valid, just different (which doesn't help you if you've got tools that are hard-coded to expect the old style).   Interestingly, `x.YesNo.Value == YesNo.Yes` generates the older style, which makes it appear that it's to do with the handling of Nullable enums.

Comment: @Will, yes, `x.YesNo.Value == YesNo.Yes` generates the old style. I have also found that. However, that means you need to check null or using Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault all the time if you want to use some Nullable enum.

Comment: As `YesNo` is ultimately numeric, I'm very surprised it's generating string literals in the SQL.  I would expect to see `1`, not `'Y'` -- how did that even get chopped?!  There's more going on here with BLToolkit by the looks of things, maybe config of some kind that defines mappings? Ultimately it's looking like BLToolkit needs updating to work with the new Roslyn-generated expressions.

Comment: @Will, you are right. We have came up the conclusion that BLToolkit needs update. We have fix this from BLToolkit's source code.